# Como llenar una lista desde 2 listas obteniendo un solo valor en especifico en java

Tags: java, arraylist

tengo un problema, lo que pasa es quiero recorrer una lista que tiene un valor que quiero utilizar para otra lista, es decir, en una tengo varios elementos ya cargados y en otro un valor que no tiene en la primer lista:

Se me ocurrió una idea de crear una lista3 nueva y unir ambas listas lista1 y lista2 para que en la lista3 ya tenga todos los elementos, agrego un fragmento de codigo de lo que quiero hacer:

```
for (int i=0;i<altas.size();i++) {                                                      
                            altas.get(i).getLast4Dig();
                            LOG.info("variable..."+altas.get(i).getLast4Dig());         
                            
                        }
```

En `altas` (lista1) tengo last4Dig un valor que quiero asignarlo a otra lista que se llama `regimenAsociado` en esta tengo ya varios elementos pero no tengo el last4dig en esta lista, como puedo llenar la lista3 con todos los elementos?

Quisiera que me otorgaran algunos ejemplos para poder hacer esta mezcla por así decir, ya que requiero la lista3 para pasarselo como parametro a otro metodo, espero y me pueda ayudar por favor, si hay algo que falte con gusto lo pondré, gracias.

Comment: No es necesario usar una tercer lista, revisa en la documentación el método [ArrayList.add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-).

Comment: Hola, ya previamente usé ese metodo pero no tuve existo :( habría forma de que me proporciones un ejemplo de como realizarlo? Acabo de editar mi pregunta donde estoy accediendo al elemento que quiero obtener para asignarlos a otra lista que se llama regimenAsociado

Comment: Basicamente tu pregunta es ¿Cómo unir dos listas en java? ¿No? Es que el título está algo confuso. Las dos listas son del mismo tipo ¿verdad? Y supongo que no quieres modificar ninguna de las dos listas anteriores, quieres crear una nueva lista.

Comment: Solo quiero obtener un elemento de cierta posición de la lista altas y asignarla a la posición de regimenAsociado

Comment: Hola @JaimeMenéndez algo asi, lo que pasa es que quiero obtener un valor de una lista que si viene el elemento que quiero y pasarlo a otra lista donde viene cargada mas información, es lo que no sé como hacerlo :(

Comment: Aqui en esta liga es otra pregunta que hice, está mas completa la explicación:https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/526378/como-pasar-un-elemento-de-una-lista-a-otra-lista-en-java

Comment: Sinceramente mi consejo es *"Simplifica tu problema y elabora un ejemplo mínimo verificable en el que reflejes tu problema y otras personas puedan reproducir"*. Tal y cómo están las dos preguntas tienes un montón de código totalmente irrelevante a la pregunta que lo hace bastante ilegible y disminuye la probabilidad que alguien te ayude. Nadie conoce tu lógica de negocio, nadie sabe cómo lucen tus clases por dentro ni cómo las estás usando y realmente, no parece importar para lo que estás preguntando. Intenta reproducir con un código sencillo y simple el problema que tienes y lo que quieres.

Comment: Si tu problema es ¿Como unir dos listas? Aquí te dejo un [pequeño demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Cgnlywkyu) de dos formas en las que puedes hacerlo. Si tu problema es cómo agregar o acceder a un elemento de la lista, ahí también está, pero por favor, simplifica tu problema y verás que tus preguntas tendrán mucha más aceptación. Muchas veces en el camino de aislar y simplificar, tu mismo encontrarás la respuesta.

Comment: Hola buenas noches, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero ahi por ejemplo según tengo entendido se tiene que hacer una iteración, es decir, recorrer en la lista que tiene el elemento deseado, de ahi obtener y posteriormente asignarlo a la posición de la lista donde hace falta el elemento?

Answer (score 1):

lo solucioné de esta manera:

```
for (int i=0;i<altas.size();i++) {
                                //for para recorrer la lista "regimen" al que se le tiene que asignar el valor
                                    for(int j=0;j<regimenAsociado.size();j++) {                                                                 
                                            if(altas.get(i).getAcctNum().equals(regimenAsociado.get(j).getAcctNum())) {
                                            regimenAsociado.get(j).setLast4Dig(altas.get(i).getLast4Dig());
                                        }
                                    }

                            }
```

Voy recorriendo lista por lista validando dentro del if si son las mismas cuentas y como son iguales siempre va a entrar y va a setear lo que tiene de altas a la lista de regimenAsociados, espero que les sirva, saludos.